# Return yes or no of value in field has changed

Tags: sql

Pretty new to SQL, so apologise if this is an easy one.
I am wanting to return a "Y" or "N" depending on whether the value has changed in a column. From the table below I want to return a Y for Dave and an N for Brad since Dave had a change to his EE_Status and Brad did NOT have a change to EE_status. Any of the fields in the table may or may not change, but the only one I want to know if it changed was EE_Status and I want to return 1 row per EE.

So, I would want the results to look like this

```
EE_ID      EE_Name        Had Status Change  
    1       Dave          Y
    2       Brad          N
```

The SQL I have written, returns a Y for both EEs.

```
Select Distinct EE_ID, EE_Name,
CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM EE_JOB J2 WHERE J.EE_STATUS <> J2.EE_STATUS) Then 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS "Had Status Change" FROM JOB J
```

Table Name: EE_JOB

```
EE_ID   EE_Name    EE_DEPT    EE_Status  Date
1       Dave       Sales      T          02/01/2017
1       Dave       Sales      A          01/01/2017
2       Brad       Market     A          12/152016
2       Brad       Dev        A          05/05/2016
```

Thanks for your help!!

Craig

Comment: Tag the DBMS please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A variation on Gordon's answer would be to check if the distinct number of `EE_STATUS` be greater than one, implying a status change took place at least once.

```
SELECT EE_ID, EE_NAME,
       CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT EE_Status) > 1
            THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS HadStatusChange
FROM EE_JOB
GROUP BY EE_ID, EE_NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

How about just checking the minimum and maximum values?

```
select ee_id, ee_name,
       (case when min(status) = max(status) then 'N' else 'Y'
        end) as HadStatusChange
from t
group by ee_id, ee_name
```